# ArgoCD - applicationset does not generate applications

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I cannot make applicationset to generate applications, I'm using this config:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: apps
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
    - git:
        repoURL: git@github.com:test/test.git
        revision: master
        directories:
          - path: apps/values/app1/*
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
      namespace: argocd
    spec:
      project: test
      source:
        repoURL: git@github.com:test/test.git
        path: apps
        targetRevision: master
        helm:
          releaseName: test
          valueFiles:
            - values/app1/development.yaml
      destination:
        server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
        namespace: test
```

I delibarately removed all templated syntax, ie. '{{...}}' to simplify things. The Helm repo is in the same repository (templates, values and Chart files).

Here the folder structure:

```
--apps
----Chart.yaml
----templates
----application-set.yaml   <=== specified above
----values
------app1
--------development.yaml   <=== it will contain more environment
```

Can you spot what the issue is?

PS. Logs of applicationset controller showed only that nothing is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, there's no directories under `apps/values/app1/`: there's only one Yaml file.

Thus the ApplicationSet doesn't see any directory and doesn't generate any Application.